# How to improve my glm model with hundreds of potential predictors and millions of observations?

Tags: r, regression, generalized-linear-model, modeling, model

I know the question is a bit general but I am a bit stuck.

I am using a glm model with the binomial family to predict if a specific occurrence is going to happen or not. The problem is I have more than 150 potential predictors and millions of observations. I am struggling to improve the model. I an=m using the `p value` to evaluate if a certain predictor should be in the model but I am facing a problem that the most of the predictors have some type of influence because it is such a huge dataset. For now I have been choosing the predictors hierarchically based on my knowledge but the model does not seem to improve, the highest `Veal-Zimmerman pseudo R2` that I got was about 0.08. I also checked out the `Brier Score` but whatever predictors I include in the model it is about 0.03. The struggle I am facing is basically how to choose the right predictors, and how to actually know if the model is good or not. The more I am reading online the more confused I am getting.

Is there a more efficient way to see which of the potential predictors have the highest predictive power and based on what to actually the models fit?